# Using De Morgans Laws in R

Tags: r, set

My question says DeMorgan's Laws in R notation are.

```
!(A&B)==(!A)|(!B)
!(A|B)==(!A)&(!B)
```

Then it says use truth tables to confirm each equality.
I Just started learning R so I am not familiar with complex coding.

What I did is try to prove both of them using an example.

```
A <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
B <- c(1,1,0,0,1)
!(A&B)==(!A)|(!B)
!(A|B)==(!A)&(!B)
```

Output

```
> A <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
> B <- c(1,1,0,0,1)
> !(A&B)==(!A)|(!B)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> !(A|B)==(!A)&(!B)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

They are both suppose to give same answers isnt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an order of operations problem.  See `?Syntax` and add parentheses like this:

```
A <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
B <- c(1,1,0,0,1)

(!(A&B))==((!A)|(!B))
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

(!(A|B))==((!A)&(!B))
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: What do you mean by order of operations sir ?

Comment: `==` has a higher precedence than other logical operators according to `?Syntax` so  `!(A|B)==(!A)&(!B)` from the question is the same as `!((A|B)==(!A))&(!B)` which is clearly not what you intended.